# Pointers about resizing text area

Tags: javascript, regex, textarea

Need some help/pointers....

When the user will click on a p element i want it content to be displayed in an text area so it would be possible to modify the text and etc...

The text area will be of a fixed width.Thus when the last character will be at the right border it will go automatically on a lower row. In this case, in order to make a new row, should i count how many characters fit in the text area fixed width and each time this number is met to add a new row?

Also in the case that the user will break the line before it reaches the right border, should i search for a \n RegExp?(with .match()?)

I think that those 2 cases need to be is a timeInterval(setTimeout perhaps?) to check on a milliseconds basis the all typing that happens. I'm trying to do it with pure Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="p1">text text text text text text text text text text text,
            text text text text text text text text text text text,
            text text text text text text text text text text text,
            text text text text text text text text text text text.
        </p>
        <div id="holder"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var text_to_copy = document.getElementById('p1').textContent;
            //every row with a fixed text area width fits 62 characters
            var input = document.createElement("textarea");
            var holder = document.getElementById("holder");

            document.getElementById('p1').onclick = function(){

                holder.appendChild(input);
                input.id = "textarea_id";
                input.style.width = "412px";
                input.value = text_to_copy.replace(/\s{1,}/g, ' ');

                if(text_to_copy.match('\n')){
                    input.rows +=1;
                }

                /*setTimeout(function(){
                    if ((text_to_copy.length % 62) == 0){

                        input.rows += 1;
                    }
                },300);*/
            }
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note. I thought that \n means break line(e.g. when user is pressing enter). Does it also includes simple white spaces?
I'm asking because alert(text_to_copy.search('\n')); returns 55

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the textarea height to match the scroll height using the clientHeight vs scrollHeight

Here is a working copy of your code

```js
var text_to_copy = document.getElementById('p1').textContent;
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
var holder = document.getElementById("holder");

document.getElementById('p1').onclick = function(){

  holder.appendChild(input);
  input.id = "textarea_id";
  input.style.width = "412px";
  input.value = text_to_copy.replace(/\s{1,}/g, ' ');

  //This function reset the textarea height base on his content. (when text is added/removed)
  var setTextAreaHeight = function(){
    input.style.height = '5px'; // Set to minimum height possible to create vertical scroll bars
    input.style.height = input.scrollHeight + 'px'; // remove the scroll bars
  }

  //call it once
  setTextAreaHeight();

  //attach to changes/key pressing.
  input.onkeydown = setTextAreaHeight;
  input.onkeyup = setTextAreaHeight;
  input.onchange = setTextAreaHeight;
};
```

```html
        <p id="p1">text text text text text text text text text text text,
            text text text text text text text text text text text,
            text text text text text text text text text text text,
            text text text text text text text text text text text.
        </p>
        <div id="holder"></div>
```